# dynamic generation of datagrid from the code-behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

Hi I have two asp:datagrid **x** and **y**, I load the data into the **datagrid x**,
I want to skip the rows in the **datagrid y** where  the datakeys of the **x** are matching those of the **y**.I have the logic in place in the **itemdatabound** event of **datagrid y** but unable to figure out the way to skip the whole row when the datakey matches one in the **datagrid x**.Could someone help me with this please

Comment: can you show us what you have attempted to do

Comment: We need to see the iteration of the datagrids.

Comment: There must be some condition to the data in your `y` datagrid, therefore you could select data from the table where the data's *not in* your `y` query.

Comment: How are you binding the datagrids?  If you are binding them in the code behind?  Show some code on how you are binding them.

Comment: thank you for your comments, I found the **e.Item.Visible = False'** worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Below is the logic you need to implement:-

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowsAdded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowsAdded

    If (row need to be removed) then
        DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex))
    End If

End Sub
```